# How to add two functions f(x,n) and f(x,m) and integrate the product of these two functions?

Tags: python, numpy, sympy

I want to integrate the product of two functions, but it seems like i keep gettin an error

AttributeError: 'Mul' object has no attribute 'cos'

```
import numpy as np
import sympy as sp

x = sp.symbols('x')

dp_xi = []
dp_eta = []

        
for n in range (1,5,1):
    for m in range (1,5,1):
        dp_xi.append(np.cos((n-2)*(np.pi/180)*x)*(n-2)*np.pi/180)
        dp_eta.append(np.cos((m-2)*(np.pi/180)*x)*(m-2)*np.pi/180)
                   
        df_xi = sum(dp_xi)
        df_eta = sum(dp_eta)

I = sp.integrate(df_xi*df_eta, (x, 0, 1))

print("I=",I)
```

Any ideas?? Thank you

I tried to replace np with sp but the integral wouldn't work

Comment: create a new function that is the product of the two functions and integrate it: something like this: new_func = lambda x : func_1(x)* func_2(x)

Comment: You're mixing symbolic math functions with numeric functions. If you're trying to construct a symbolic expression, you'll need to use sympy functions throughout. Numpy can't compute the cosine of a symbolic expression in terms of `x` because that's not a number

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips. It usually helps to post the [full error message with traceback](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146/4518341).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, you should use only symbols if you want to use analytical integration.

```
n = sp.symbols('n')
f = sp.cos((n-2)*(sp.pi/180*x)*(n-2)*sp.pi/180)
sp.integrate(f, (x, 0, 1))
```

Comment: Thank you, but if I want to get numerical results is Scipy useful ??

Comment: absolutely useful. if you want to "define" the integral, just add another parameter in integral part.

ex: sp.integrate(f, (x, 0, 1), (n, 0, 1))

Answer (score 1):

Where's the FULL ERROR message?

Look at what I get when running your code

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
AttributeError: 'Mul' object has no attribute 'cos'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[25], line 9
      7 for n in range (1,5,1):
      8     for m in range (1,5,1):
----> 9         dp_xi.append(np.cos((n-2)*(np.pi/180)*x)*(n-2)*np.pi/180)
     10         dp_eta.append(np.cos((m-2)*(np.pi/180)*x)*(m-2)*np.pi/180)
     12         df_xi = sum(dp_xi)

TypeError: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type Mul which has no callable cos method
```

It points to the line with the `np.cos`.  Running that expression by itself:

```
In [26]: np.cos((n-2)*(np.pi/180)*x)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
AttributeError: 'Mul' object has no attribute 'cos'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[26], line 1
----> 1 np.cos((n-2)*(np.pi/180)*x)

TypeError: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type Mul which has no callable cos method
```

Strip off the `cos`, and we see the argument is:

```
In [28]: print((n-2)*(np.pi/180)*x)
-0.0174532925199433*x
```

The short answer, as others explain, `np.cos` cannot be used a `sympy.symbol` or expression.

`sympy`'s own `cos` runs, though, since `x` is still a symbol, it won't try to return a numeric value:

```
In [30]: print(sp.cos((n-2)*(np.pi/180)*x))
cos(0.0174532925199433*x)
```

With `sp` instead:

```
In [33]: print(df_xi)
2*pi*cos(pi*x/90)/45

In [34]: print(df_eta)
2*pi*cos(pi*x/90)/45
```

And the integral:

```
In [35]: I = sp.integrate(df_xi*df_eta, (x, 0, 1))
In [37]: print(I)
8*pi*(sin(pi/90)*cos(pi/90)/2 + pi/180)/45
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine with sp instead of np if you dedent the code in which `sum` is used. (In addition, there is no need for a double loop since each expression only depends on one loop variable.)

```py
import sympy as sp

x = sp.symbols('x')

a = [sp.cos((n-2)*(sp.pi/180)*x)*(n-2)*sp.pi/180 for n in range(1, 5)]
                   
df_xi = 4*sum(a)
df_eta = df_xi.subs(n, m)

I = sp.integrate(df_xi*df_eta, (x, 0, 1)) # or sp.Integral(df_xi*df_eta, (x, 0, 1))

print("I=",I)
```

outputs

```
I= 8*pi*(sin(pi/90)*cos(pi/90)/2 + pi/180)/45
```

which evaluates to

```py
>>> I.n()
0.0194875985645024
```

Comment: but if I want to get numerical results is Scipy useful ??

Comment: see last line of answer -- and you don't have to actually do the integral before evaluating. You can replace `integrate` with `Integral` and still do `I.n()` to get the numerical value.